# Editable PDF using itext (5.3.0) in java. Not able to save data in Adobe Reader X

Tags: java, itext, adobe-reader

I am able to create Editable PDF using itext (5.3.0) in java. I have used **Adobe Reader X**.

Question :

**Adobe Reader X**

I want save my PDF with data which I have entered in text box but it shows below message.

"Please fill out the following form. You can not save data typed into this form
Please print your completed form if you would like a copy for your record".

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of Adobe Reader (i.e. before Adobe Reader XI) only allowed saving of form entries if the PDF has originally been specially prepared. This preparing step is called *Reader-enabling a PDF form for saving user-entered data* and is done by applying a special kind of signature, cf. section 12.8.2.3 of the [PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) on the UR transform for usage rights signatures.

*Reader-enabling* is only possible using special Adobe software (e.g. the Adobe Acrobat or some Adobe LifeCycle component) unless you have extracted the private key from one of those products which certainly is not allowed.

Read e.g. [this tutorial](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/reader-enabling-a-pdf-form-for-saving-user-entered-data) for an explanation how to Reader-enable a PDF form for saving user-entered data.

PS: Due to your original choice of tags your question did not catch my eye when you first posted it. I think other readers also missed it for that reason. Thus, choose your starting tags wisely.