# Save user input PDF Template with iText

Tags: java, templates, pdf, itext

I have a pdf form where user enters some info, like name and address.
Using iText, can I save new pdf file with user input?  How can I get the text value of what user entered like this, stamper.getAcroFields().setField("name", nameTextBox.text);?  Many sample codes use hard coded value but I want use what user entered in the textbox.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/temp/Template.pdf");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/TemplateTest.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileOutputStream);

//Can I do something like this?

stamper.getAcroFields().setField("name", nameTextBox.text);
stamper.getAcroFields().setField("address", addressTextBox.text);
stamper.getAcroFields().setField("city", cityTextBox.text);
stamper.getAcroFields().setField("zip", zipTextBox.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a PDF where the user enters some info.

**Question 1: how can the user submit the form data?**

[a.] The user **can not** safe the PDF locally, **unless** the document is Reader-enabled *or* if the user has a version of Adobe Acrobat (not Reader). Reader-enabling a document can only be done with Adobe software; see [Editable PDF using itext (5.3.0) in java. Not able to save data in Adobe Reader X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523466/editable-pdf-using-itext-5-3-0-in-java-not-able-to-save-data-in-adobe-reader)

[b.] The user can **submit** the fields to a server. This can be done in the form of a querystring, an FDF file, or an XFDF file. If the form is Reader-enabled or if the user has Acrobat, he can also submit the complete filled-in PDF to the server.

**Question 2: how can you store the form data in a PDF?**

If the user submits the complete PDF, then you do not need to store the form data in the PDF. It is already there. You can retrieve the info like this:

```
String name = reader.getAcroFields().getField("name");
```

If you get the information as a querystring, just examine the key/value pairs and use the code you already have in your question. If the information is stored in an FDF file, you need `FdfReader`. IF the information is stored in an XFDF file, you need `XfdfReader`.

**Question 3: how do you use what the user entered in the textbox?**

This question is unclear. What are you talking about?

If the text box is a text box in the PDF, see [a.] under question 1.

If the text box is a text box in a web page, see [b.] under question 1.

If the text box is a text box in some standalone application, see the answer to question 2.

All in all, your questions are of very poor quality. When you say 'many samples use hard coded value', it is clear that you didn't read the official documentation.